# Is there a shared calendar for events of Guild Wars?

Tags: guild-wars

I search an RSS or ICS (Ical) feed to add to my Calandrier with events (Zaishen or special events) of Guild Wars. I'm surprised not to find.

Answer (score 4):

For some of the quests you can syndicate the GW Wiki Twitter feed, which keeps up to date with all the current Zaishen quests and Sandford collections.

https://twitter.com/#!/GuildWarsWiki

As for the community special events, they are mostly centred around real world holiday's so they are probably already in your calendar. Such as Christmas, Easter, St Patricks Day, Chinese New Year, Halloween. Best thing is to keep an eye on the Guild Wars homepage or the Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

It became a habit for me to look it up in the official Wiki since there you have a real nice summary of current and near future quests.
http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Daily_activities

I also like, that its easy to look up the rewards to see if its worth to do the quest and if so a walktrough (if needed) only 1 click away!

Comment: I originally created the prediction templates on Guildwiki to make a calendar of events ( http://www.guildwiki.org/User:Kirbman/Calendar ) and later ported the templates over to Guild Wars Wiki, where they were used to make that Daily activities page.

I prefer the calendar format for planning, but check it out and decide for yourself.